# Using Video Textures for Shading & Displacement

Tags: shaders, image, video, displacement

This video was made in Blender, and has a seemingly straightforward effect that I'm still struggling to figure out how to do.

Here are two gifs I made for reference:

[RAMEN sign](https://i.imgur.com/y4iX48k.gif)
[Trees](https://i.imgur.com/CYjF2Se.gif%3C)

In the clips, it seems like a glitch overlay video was made in After Effects, then used as both a displacement texture and a shader that wraps over the geometry of the object (such as the trees). I've used video sequences as displacements before, but I've never been able to use a video texture as an overlay as it appears in the video. Is it just Image Texture > MixRGB w/ the model's actual material nodes?

Alternately, could these just be 3D model animations pre-rendered out, effects added, then brought back in as 2D image planes? I could maybe see that for the trees, but the "RAMEN" sign seems to have dimensional displacement to it.

Comment: You could achive that with After effects, you need to render a model and add like glich effects (for the trees). With After Effects, also the Ramen Sign could be made completely. Another Option is Davinci Resolve

Comment: Thanks, I agree. Making a glitched video in AE is second nature to me. But do you think that everything in the gifs is just 2D image planes of videos made in AE, or is there any Blender input going on?

Comment: You can do "overlay" effects in Blender, even per-material overlays, by using "window" coordinates as your vector for a texture lookup.  This texture can be an image sequence or a still.  These lookups can be used in a wide variety of fashions, even for true displacement if you want.

Comment: @Nathan this seems like an appropriate answer if you could post a demo link etc